# How do I bypass the login screen using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, cookies, automation

I am currently working on a project where I am attempting to automate some of the functions that I do on a daily basis using Selenium and Python. I am aware I need to use cookies, but am completely unsure on how to go about doing that?

I have searched YouTube and many forums and I can't seem to get a straight answer.

I need help. Thank you!

Comment: Not really enough information in your ticket. What kind of authentication are you attmepting to bypass? Do you just want to login via automation?

Comment: If its a simple text field login, you can use `send_keys` to enter your credentials into the required fields.